# best way for search in rom

Tags: search, vhdl

I want compare 32bit reg with rom 1024x32 .
best way for this search?

vhdl code

Comment: First read on [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I don't understand. It looks like that you are asking us to write this function for you.... I hope that is not the case, because that's not what we do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a content-addressable memory (CAM).

The basic idea is that a CAM can be searched for values (32-bit word) to get keys (addresses). It does this by having a list of valid addresses per 32-bit word stored in some local memory.

Check out this [application note](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp1151_Param_CAM.pdf) by Xilinx for a more technical description.